# Reading regular expressions from a XML file, store them into a list of list and afterwards use them

Tags: python, regex, xml, list

I want to read many regular expressions from a XML file, store them into a list of list and use them. My solution does not work and I do not know why.

Suppose that I have a XML that contains the regex that I want to store in my list of list. The XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<my_xml>
    <field>
        <regex>\d+\.\d+</regex>
    </field>

    <field>
        <regex>\d+</regex>
    </field>
</my_xml>
```

So, I read line by line the XML file and I build my list of list containing all regex:

```
tree = ET.parse("./my_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
listOfList = []

for field in root.findall('field'):

    tmp = []
    regex = str(field.find('regex').text)
    tmp.append(regex)
    listOfList.append(tmp)
```

Now, the list of list that contains my regex is ready. In fact, if I print the `listOfList` I get:

```
[['\\d+\\.\\d+'], ['\\d+']]
```

Now, it's time to use the list of list that contains the two regex. Suppose that I have a string that contains `ver=4.0` and I want only to get `4.0`. To do that, I use the regex contained into `listOfList[0]`. Here the code:

```
 my_str = "ver=4.0"
 print re.findall(str(listOfList[0]), my_str)
```

.....but if I do that, python prints out `['.']` .

Why does python print out `['.']` instead of `4.0`? How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `listOfRegex`? You introduced the variable without defining it.

Comment: Edit your post to add all necessary elements to understand your problem and to make tests. An other example, the field tag doesn't appears in your xml string. Show more xml. In short, add the shortest code necessary to reproduce [the problem] in the question itself.

Comment: The way you have written your code makes `r'` be part of the regex. It's not.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte now it is more clear.

Comment: @raphv I removed `r'` but now it prints `['.']` and not `4.0`

Comment: @SimonKirsten I meant `listOfList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you are using

```
str(listOfList[0])
```

will in your example be

```
["r'\\d+\\.\\d+'"]
```

and that literally with the `["r'` before and `'"]` after.

The [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) functions formats the array to a string representation of the array.

You only want the actual regex not the string representation.

Use

```
re.findall(listOfList[0][0], my_str)
```

because `listOfList[0][0]` will be `\d+\.\d+` wich is the regex you need.

Comment: following the suggestion of @raphv, I removed the `r'` from the xml file. Now, `str(listOfList[0])` is `['\\d+\\.\\d+']`. I did not understand your solution, what should I do? Thanks.